# Is it a normal practice to include more than one Dockerfile in a project?

Tags: docker

If I have a web project in source control and I want to include all the necessary configuration to run it, should I be using more than one Dockerfile to define different profiles for my database, web and data containers?

Are there any examples of this practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You should either allow the profiles to be mounted in using volumes so that you can use the same container with different configurations or setup all the configurations and then allow the profile to be selected based on environment variable or commands to docker run.

The first approach is preferable as no information about your configuration bleeds into the container definition. You may even make your container public as it may be of use to other people.

Comment: Okay, so the Dockerfile at the root of my repository should really only contain anything pertaining to the operation of the PHP server, and nothing else?

Comment: Bingo. That makes it much more re-usuable by keeping your service and data/content/config separate. If you ever want to update apache etc you can just build one new container and mount the volumes there. If you ever want to change your settings you just update the file in the host machine and restart the container.

Comment: What about situations where my app itself has different executables that can be run?  If my dockerfile is running a daemon, that will limit it to one executable.  When really, I should be able to run workers and other command-line utils of my framework?

Comment: So the official party line is each executable should be its own micro-service container and the containers should link to each other. You can use fig to bring up entire group in one go. However, I understand that is not always possible (e.g. I run log rotate inside my containers). In this scenario I normally make a script, the entrypoint, the script then runs all executables in the background (So not the primary processes) and then runs tail on logs  as my primary process or even bash so I can attach and make changes. However, I want to state again this second approach is not canonical.

Comment: Keeping with the "official party line", it seems like one Dockerfile per repo is disingenous.  I use the same repository (codebase) for serving as I do my workers.  They aren't seprate projects.  With the limit of only specifying one Dockerfile per repo, does this ultimately limit me?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=docker-files+github If you google github + docker-files you will see how many people just create one  repo for all of their files. Again party line is that the docker file does not live with our other code. Its a PHP container and has nothing to do with your code. Similarly each of your micro-services should provide one well defined service and only interact with the outside world using links and volumes. In this scenario you "SHOULD" put each docker file alone in its own repo. A lot of people don't bother.

Comment: In practice its no limit, as long as each docker file is in its own folder you can setup automated builds for all your docker files even through the official dockerhub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64639/discussion-between-usman-ismail-and-omega).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only changing configuration parameters I would recommend you to reuse the Dockerfile and pass a configuration file as a parameter.

Comment: It will be more than just configuration. Each docker file would be a different executable.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what a "profile" is in this case, can you elaborate?